# What is the best way doing intervals without blocking the event loop in Node Js server?

Tags: node.js

im really new to node.js and i have a beginners question.
I plan to creat a node server that will execute a http request for a json file every 1-2 seconds.
The reason for doing a request so fast is because the json file im requesting is changing constantly.

What is the correct way doing that and not blocking the event loop?
Is it safe to put the request code in a function and call it in a setTimeout() function?
Should i run the requests in a child process?

Comment: Why do you think the "event loop would be blocked"?

Comment: How big is the json? There might be better ways to achieve this. Are you trying to read some sensors? Can you add more details of what you are doing?

Comment: @Molda The json is very small.

Comment: @torazaburo because of the constant requests? ...I assume from your comment that Node can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of asynchronicity is that it is asynchronous. When you issue the HTTP request, it is sent off more or less instantly and node returns to other business, waking up only when the response is received. The only thing that could cause a "blocking" of the event loop in your case is very intensive processing either preparing the request or processing the response.

That is why on the front page of the node website it says "node uses an event-driven, **non-blocking** I/O model".